# Why is cloning of an inflated view in Android not possible?

Tags: android, performance

Is there any specific reason why cloning of an inflated view is not allowed in android?

In a game that I'm creating, each click is resulting in inflation of 20-30 instances of the same xml.

It would be highly time saving in this scenario to create the view once and clone it whenever required.

For Example, I want to inflate a view -

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.power_block, viewGroup, false);
```

And then create copies of the view using -

```
View clonedRoot = root.clone();
```

Comment: 20-30 instances? But why?

Comment: Without code, how are we supposed to know what you are doing wrong?

Comment: "Is there any specific reason why cloning of an inflated view is not allowed in android?" -- there is nothing stopping you from writing your own cloning logic. "It would be highly time saving in this scenario to create the view once and clone it whenever required" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?  And, to echo zgc7009's concerns, why do you think that your overall approach is sensible? Having hundreds of views in a layout is a code smell.

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example of implementing a custom cloning logic?

I'm trying to create a simple game like the image below -

http://onlinefreegames4u.com/wp-content/thumbs/mochi/R/relax-blocks-2_img1.png

On clicking a color, all the blocks with same color around it should animate as objects falling down. Hence I'm creating each block as a view